How to add dotted lines TableBorder widget in flutter?
I need the bill receipt to feature dotted lines for a visually appealing UI

I would like the bill receipt to include dotted lines to create a visually appealing UI.

Table(
            border: TableBorder(
              horizontalInside: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.black,
                width: 2,
              ),
            ),


--------------------------------------
          SUPER MART

Date: 05/18/2024   Time: 12:34 PM
--------------------------------------
Item                Qty     Price
--------------------------------------
Milk (1L)           2       $2.50
Bread (1 loaf)      1       $1.99
Eggs (dozen)        1       $3.00
Apples (1 lb)       3       $1.20
Butter (250g)       1       $2.75
--------------------------------------
Subtotal:                   $12.64
Tax (5%):                   $0.63
--------------------------------------
Total:                     $13.27
--------------------------------------
      Thank you for shopping!
--------------------------------------



Please try this pub

Can you provide what you want as a picture? Do you want Dotted border or just one line to divide?

To achieve dotted lines in Flutter, you will need to use a custom painter because the TableBorder class does not support dotted borders directly. Below is an example that demonstrates how to create a receipt layout with dotted lines using a custom painter.
First, create a custom painter class to draw dotted lines:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DottedLinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double dashWidth = 5, dashSpace = 5, startX = 0;
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 1;

    while (startX < size.width) {
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(startX, 0), Offset(startX + dashWidth, 0), paint);
      startX += dashWidth + dashSpace;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}


A flutter package to easily added dotted borders around widgets.
Installing
To use this package, add dotted_border as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml file.
Usage
Wrap DottedBorder widget around the child widget
DottedBorder(
    color: Colors.black,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    child: FlutterLogo(size: 148),
)

